# Dragging of shapes on Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, mouseevent, java-2d

I am using JButton's Action listener to draw different shapes.To keep previously drawn shapes on panel all time, I've used an arraylist in which all drawn shapes has added and repaint whole list.How can I drag any shape while others display on Jpanel all the time?

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);


        System.out.println("====>>> " + s);
        switch (s) {

          case "Button1":
                Activity act = new Activity();
                act.setArcH(15);
                act.setArcW(15);
                act.setBreadth(40);
                act.setLength(50);
                act.setXpoint(x);
                act.setYpoint(y);

                //==========================================================

                obj = new ShapePoints();
                obj.setShapeId(ShapesID.ROUND_RECTANGLE_ID);
                obj.setxPoint(act.getXpoint());
                obj.setyPoint(act.getYpoint());
                obj.setLength(act.getLength());
                obj.setBreadth(act.getBreadth());
                obj.setArcW(act.getArcW());
                obj.setArcH(act.getArcH());
                shapePoints.add(obj);

                Iterator itr = shapePoints.iterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    ShapePoints sp = (ShapePoints) itr.next();

                    switch (sp.getShapeId()) {

                        case ShapesID.ARROW_ID:

                            break;
                        case ShapesID.CIRCLE_ID:

                            g.drawOval(obj.getxPoint(), obj.getyPoint(), obj.getLength(), obj.getBreadth());

                            break;


                        case ShapesID.CON_CIRCLE_ID:
                            g.drawOval(sp.getxPoint(), sp.getyPoint(), sp.getLength(), sp.getLength());
                            g.fillOval(sp.getxPoint() + 10, sp.getyPoint() + 10, sp.getBreadth() / 2, sp.getBreadth() / 2);
                            break;
                        case ShapesID.RECTANGLE_ID:

                            break;
                        case ShapesID.ROUND_RECTANGLE_ID:

                            g.drawRoundRect(obj.getxPoint(), obj.getyPoint(), obj.getLength(), obj.getBreadth(),
                                    obj.getArcW(), obj.getArcH());
                            break;
                    }
                }
                break;
```

this is for 1 button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a mouselistener and a mousemotionlistener (usually you make a single instance for both) and check wheter your shape contains the mouse pressed event or not. If yes, you keep track of where the mouse is dragged to translate your shape and continuously call `repaint()`, like usual.

- Single click creates a vertex of a polygon
- Double click creates the current drawn polygon (if it has at least 3 vertices) and we create a new one
- Right-click clears the current drawn polygon and creates a new one
- Press/Drag/Release moves the polygon located under the mouse (if there are several, it takes the first one found. it would probably better to make a reverse for-loop)

Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestNaming {

    private static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 600;
    private static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 600;

    public static class Drawing extends JPanel {

        private static final Font FONT = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);

        private List<Polygon> polygons = new ArrayList<Polygon>();

        private Polygon currentPolygon = new Polygon();

        private MouseAdapter mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {

            private Polygon dragged;
            private Point lastLocation;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                for (Polygon p : polygons) {
                    if (p.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                        dragged = p;
                        lastLocation = e.getPoint();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                if (dragged != null) {
                    dragged.translate(e.getX() - lastLocation.x, e.getY() - lastLocation.y);
                    lastLocation = e.getPoint();
                    repaint();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                dragged = null;
                lastLocation = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                        addPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    } else if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        createPolygon();
                    }
                } else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    clearCurrentPolygon();
                }
            }

        };

        public Drawing() {
            addMouseListener(mouseListener);
            addMouseMotionListener(mouseListener);
        }

        protected void addPoint(int x, int y) {
            currentPolygon.addPoint(x, y);
            repaint();
        }

        protected void clearCurrentPolygon() {
            currentPolygon = new Polygon();
            repaint();
        }

        protected void createPolygon() {
            if (currentPolygon.npoints > 2) {
                polygons.add(currentPolygon);
            }
            clearCurrentPolygon();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.setFont(FONT);
            for (Polygon polygon : polygons) {
                drawPolygon(g, polygon);
            }
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            drawPolygon(g, currentPolygon);
        }

        private void drawPolygon(Graphics g, Polygon polygon) {
            if (polygon.npoints < 3) {
                if (polygon.npoints == 1) {
                    g.fillOval(polygon.xpoints[0] - 2, polygon.ypoints[0] - 2, 4, 4);
                    drawNthPoint(g, polygon, 0);
                } else if (polygon.npoints == 2) {
                    g.drawLine(polygon.xpoints[0], polygon.ypoints[0], polygon.xpoints[1], polygon.ypoints[1]);
                    drawNthPoint(g, polygon, 0);
                    drawNthPoint(g, polygon, 1);
                }
            } else {
                g.drawPolygon(polygon);
                for (int i = 0; i < polygon.npoints; i++) {
                    drawNthPoint(g, polygon, i);
                }
            }
        }

        private void drawNthPoint(Graphics g, Polygon polygon, int nth) {
            // Only works 26 times!
            String name = Character.toString((char) ('A' + nth));
            int x = polygon.xpoints[nth];
            int height = g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
            int y = polygon.ypoints[nth] < height ? polygon.ypoints[nth] + height : polygon.ypoints[nth];
            Rectangle2D stringBounds = g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(name, g);
            g.drawString(name, x, y);
        }

    }

    protected static void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Drawing());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```